# Chart.js - What is the equivalent of the Scatter chart for a Bar chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, bar-chart

I made recently a Scatter chart, basically a simple line, but where I could define the data on both axis, Y and X.

Now I need to do the same but with a bar chart, and for what I am seeing, I Can only put labels on the X-axis in a bar chart, is there a way to actual put data on both axis?

In my scatter type chart I had the data as array of [{y: .., x: ..}]

Any way to achieve this in a bar chart? thank you

Comment: Please provide more details or code or jsfiddle?

Comment: more details about what? I can't find an equivalent of the Scatter chart (a simple line chart) where I could put data for both axis, in the Bar chart! How can I make a Bar chart where it's me defining data for X and Y?

Comment: do you have any image which you need to implement?

Comment: the end result is the following, a bar chart with, on the Y axis the number of students (dynamic, I get this value from an observable), on the X axis the grade they got in a specific exam (each exam has a Bar chart). 
So each Bar will rapresent the number of students that got a specific grade.
On the Y axis I will have the number of students with stepSize of 1, and on the Xaxis I will have all the possible grades, in stepsizes of 1.
I recieve an object that has each student and its grade, so now I need to implement this in the Bar chart, but can't put data on the X axis, only labels